# configparser NoSectionError Python

Tags: python, config, configparser

I have made a config file named "config.cfg" that's on the same folder of my .py file.
My config file is like this:

```
[NetAccess]
host=localhost
port=3306

[Credentials]
username=myuser
password=mypass

[Database]
name=mydb
```

in my .py file I have this code:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
__DBMSuser = config.get('Credentials', 'username')
__DBMSpsw = config.get('Credentials', 'password')
```

When I launch my program, I receive this error:

`configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Credentials'`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. My code was correct, and the .cfg file was correctly saved in the folder of my program, but because of other parts of my code, my current directory changed to "C:/Windows/Service32". Not reading the file, I had not error until I was trying to read the sections, so I got NoSectionError.
To solve it, I've choice a standard folder (in AppData) where to save my file and read it and then I've used the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. Most likely the issue is reading the config file itself. Config Parser's read method is configured to fail silently if it fails to find or read the file, but the read function returns a read_ok boolean flag. Use it to check if the read was successful:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

filename = 'config.cfg'
read_ok = config.read(filename)

if read_ok:
    __DBMSuser = config['Credentials']['username']
    __DBMSpsw = config['Credentials']['password']

else:
    print(f'Could not read file {filename}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in your code, cuz it works for me.

I think there is some small error with file:

- Make sure your file is in same directory as python file
- Have you saved your file? maybe you forgot to press ctrl+s
- If even that's not working for you, try another version of Python